# Pass data to another html and save

Tags: python, html, django

can someone please tell me how to send all content of input.html to approve.html. I want the approve.html to validate input.html and then save it to the database. How can I do that? I'm a newbie, please help me, I've been trying to solve the problem for 7 days.

```
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="mail">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="msg">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>

      <button class="menü_button"><b>send</b></button>
    </li>

  </ul>
</form>
```

```
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="mail">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="msg">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>

      <button class="menü_button"><b>save</b></button>
    </li>
    <li>

      <button class="menü_button"><b>remote</b></button>
    </li>

  </ul>
</form>
```

I use django

Comment: Hey, always happy to help, but we would need more details as to what you'd want to do, and how the project is currently set up.

Comment: A good jumping-off point for this would be to understand the different components in a web application (frontend, backend, database) and different methodologies (client-side vs. server-side rendering).

Comment: After I press "send" in input.html, an email is sent via views.py. In the email there is a link that then forwards to approve.html and I want the entire content with the information (name...) to be displayed on the approve.html. Then I want to save the information in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than sending the email and sending back the data from user to you, why not save it in database with an extra field named approved `False`. Like this:

```
class UserComment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    message = models.TextField(...)
    email = models.EmailField(...)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

On upon storing, you can generate a link with the uuid for the database entry and send it to user for clicking for validating. If he validates, then just make the approved field True.

Answer (score 0):

When `views.py` send the email, the link should have the data you want to pass as query parameters:

```
youdomain.com/approve.html?user_name=JaneDoe&email=janedow@gmail.com&...
```

When the user clicks on the link in the email and arrives at `youdomain.com/approve.html`, a javascript script can be run to extract the data from the URL and insert it into the approve.html form.

Javascript to extract data from QueryString:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```